# Problems with rendering cloth and hair with cycles

Tags: rendering, cloth-simulation, hair

I should render (with cycles) an animation of a character of a hairy monster with a cloth.
When I try to render one of the latest frames of the action, it has two problems:

1. the cloth is all deformed (I tried to set the subdivision surface with equal numbers for render and viewport, as I read in other answers, but it still has big problems)
   2)the hair sometimes isn't visible (especially after baking) or is messed up. I've tried different times with render properties > feature set "experimental" and hair shape > 3d curves.

Is there any particular setting for rendering hair and cloth??? [image: in the 3d viewport I see this type of error in some frames][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RPpr.png)[image][image]

Comment: I recommend not using cloth for these clothes, since they appear fairly tight.

Comment: And what kind of physics do you recommend to use? This cloth is parented with the rig, I need it to move with the body. However in the frame 1 it looks normal, without these deformations, so I think they are caused by the speed of the movement, but I can't understand what I can do.

Comment: I think you should not use cloth physics at all. Just deform the suit with the armature

Comment: @TheLabCat  Sorry for the delay, but thank you!! I did what you said and the cloth is so much better now for the animation!

Comment: Your welcome, and PTL! 